# Export data from firebase database to excel sheet

Tags: java, android, excel, firebase

I have created an attendance app using firebase database, I want a function that will export attendance record from firebase to excel sheet , using a single button inside my android app.

Comment: Sure, there are Java libraries to create Excel files and read from Firebase. What have you tried?

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: Actually I'm searching about it . Searched on Google but didn't find any solution. please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.